# Mule 3: Controlling whether a flow is allowed to be executed

Tags: esb, mule

**My current situation:**

I currently have a Mule ESB application with three flows which process messages originating from two different sources, these three flows are tied together using a VM queue.

**Flow #1:**

Inbound (Endpoint #1) -> (Perform message processing and transformations) -> Outbound (Endpoint #3)

**Flow #2:**

Inbound (Endpoint #2) ->  (Perform message processing and transformations) -> Outbound (Endpoint #3)

**Flow #3**

Inbound (Endpoint #3) -> (Perform message processing and transformations, do stuff) -> Outbound

**Problem/ Issue:**

Now what I want to do is introduce a fourth flow, Flow #4, that gets state information from an inbound endpoint and based off this information be able to prevent Flow #3 from ever being executed/ prevent it from processing its inbound messages.

In other words, what I'd ideally like is to have Flow #4 run at the startup of the ESB application (like all flows seem to automatically do), and based on the state information it gets from its inbound message, prevent/ allow or enable/ disable Flow #3 from ever processing messages from Endpoint #3.

The following are what I ideally require:

**Requirements:**

1. Must be able to accomplish solely through the mule flow XML, no additional POJO/ custom Java objects.
2. Flow #4 must be performed at startup of the ESB application and only the first inbound message needs to ever be processed.
3. Ideally, I don't want Flow #3 to have a composite inbound source or have to evaluate every inbound message the state of some global variable.

What's the best way to accomplish what I want to do?

If there is no real good solution, then if I must omit #3 requirement, then what's the best way to accomplish such a global variable that is shared between two independent flows that aren't tied together by some outbound -> inbound endpoint in the XML config?  I've tried using session properties, but they require that the flows be tied together as either subflows or by an endpoint.

Thanks.

Comment: I was about to propose #3, ie. using a global variable in the Mule registry. Why is this not acceptable? Also, though no custom Java class will be needed, some MEL/Groovy scripting will be.

Comment: Well, again the requirements, especially #3 is just what I'd ideally like.  But if there's no better solution or way to accomplish the desired behavior then it's my last resort.

How would a global variable like this be done in the XML config?  How do I declare globally a variable in the XML outside of the flows and reference it in the flows?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a global property and a few MEL expressions to make this happen:

```
<global-property name="gate_open" value="true" />

<flow name="gated-flow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="gated.in" />
    <expression-filter expression="#[app.registry.gate_open]" />
    ...
</flow>


<flow name="gate-controller">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="gate.in"  />
    <expression-component>
      app.registry.gate_open = false
    </expression-component>
</flow>
```

Sending any message to `vm://gate.in` will close the gate and `gated-flow` will stop processing the messages it receives.

You can use any protocol you want instead of VM.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That's significantly more simplistic and cleaner a solution than I thought it would be.

Comment: It looks like this is designed to accept only one message: both flows get the message from the end-point and one flow closes the other flow. I was wondering if this might create a race condition whereby one of two unpleasant things might occur: 1) the controller flows shuts down the gated flow before the first message is processes or 2) a second message might slip thru gated before the first message in the controller flow has a chance to change the variable value.

Comment: "both flows get the message from the end-point" : negative, they listen to two different VM queues: `gated.in` and `gate.in`.

Comment: How would you do this for a flow that you want turn off but it's not VM inbound, but Poll or AMQP Inbound. Set the poll to a high number? and use the expression-filter as above but with a java property? (I want to disable input flows by config)

Comment: @dlite922 Stopping the flow will stop its message sources.