# Settings for Quartz scheduler - Mule

Tags: quartz-scheduler, mule, scheduler

I have developed a Mule(3.3) application consisting of multiple scheduled events using Quartz end-point.
I have created a mule-config.xml and deployed it in Mule server, and i can see events triggered at specified time.

Now, I need to implement a feature where i can have setting (configured in properties file or XML file) to ON/OFF the quartz scheduler. 
ON means the event to be triggered and OFF means the events not to be triggered. But i cannot see any such settings in Mule.

Any pointers as how to solve this will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, instead of trying to pause/restart the endpoint, I would let the Quartz events fire but switch-off downstream processing with something similar to what's discussed here: [Mule 3: Controlling whether a flow is allowed to be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885181/mule-3-controlling-whether-a-flow-is-allowed-to-be-executed)