# Mule 3.7: start specific flow before others

Tags: mule

I've a flow that loads data from postgres, I want this flow be executed before the others flows, I have many flows. I'm trying to do this in Mule 3.7

I have sereral http inbounds, almost all of them needs this flow that loads data from postgres, so they can't be private

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the flows that you want to execute later, make their initial state stopped as follows :- `<flow name="..." initialState="stopped">`
Now all the flows that you don't want to execute will not run when the application is deployed.

Now at the end to the flow that loads data from postgres, after the data is loaded from DB, **start** all the flows that are **stopped** as follows :-

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('targetFlow').start()
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

This will start all the other flows that are stopped and will execute after that flow you want and I hope that satisfies your requirement.

Comment: I use this strategy, but instead of using groovy I use <expression-component>app.registry.targetFlowName.start();</expression-component>

Answer (score 1):

With limited context provided in your questions,  One-way to do is make the flow you want to run 1st as `public`(meaning, define an inbound-endpoint) and make other flows as `private`, you call that explicity using `flow-ref`

**EDIT:** You could have a variable say `loadCache`defined in  object-store with initial value of `false` and when you other flows run, first thing they check is if `loadCache` is still `false`, then call the `loadData` flow and `loadData` flow on completion will set the value of variable to `true`. so any other flow needing cache data, would check this variable and based on that use `cache` data or call function to load data

Something like this:

```
<flow...>
        ....
   <!-- flows with http or other inbounds -->
   <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore__Configuration" key="cacheLoad" defaultValue-ref="#[false]" targetProperty="flowVars.cacheLoad" doc:name="retrieve cacheLoad"/>

</flow>

<flow> ... 
   <!--load data from postgress-->
   <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore__Configuration" key="cacheLoad" value-ref="#[true]" doc:name="store cacheLoad"/>              

</flow>
```

Object-store reference https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-object-stores

The other option could be to use registry object instead of object store https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/storing-objects-in-the-registry

Comment: I have sereral http inbounds, almost all of them needs this flow that loads data from postgres, so they can't be private

Comment: please explain your case better. When you say _I want this flow be executed before the others flows_ do you mean right before your other public flows get triggered or first thing in morning or what?

Comment: I need to execute this flow before others when starting mule, because I load data from postgres and save the data in memory, then in the others flows I get the data from memory, this way I don't need to execute the query again.

Comment: When does this cache expire? how do you plan to reload data in memory?

Comment: I have quartz that reload the data every 2 hours

Comment: this solution is very similar to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885181/mule-3-controlling-whether-a-flow-is-allowed-to-be-executed

Comment: yes you could use that app.registry solution or see my update

Comment: now looking into detail, app.registrry solution, you don't need expression filter, you'd still use solution similar to I suggested just that you have a choice between storing variable in app.registry or object-store

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105287/discussion-between-sergio-abreu-and-charu-khurana).

Answer (score 0):

You can load  all your dependent flows in a stopped state and let your core flow start first, once it starts successfully you can then trigger the start of the rest of the flows in the order in which you want.